# Xcode can't commit without checkout

Tags: xcode, git, svn, version-control

When I create a new project, I can't find the way to commit the project to remote server(github,svn), even the repository address is right. Every time I have to check out the project from the remote server, then commit the added file. Maybe there are other way to do that, because I think it is reasonable to commit the new project to server(github, svn).

when create the project, the source control can't be use, even i have chosen the 
 [image]

the source control doesn't support commit

[image]

even my repository address is right, copy from the github. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new project and add it to the git server from xcode? Are you sure that your local git is created. If you get a popup like this then your repository is not created and you'll not be able to commit. Instead of creating the repo in local try it in the remote server.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to push local Git repos to GitHub is by using GitHub for Mac: https://mac.github.com

It's a free GUI tool that allows you to push a repo created with Xcode or the command line to GitHub with one click. Since the remote is saved in the Git repo, Xcode will pick it up when you open your project the next time. From then on you'll be able to push and pull with Xcode.